# How do I replace a missing value in a column with the value immediately above throughout a table?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a large table (7000 rows × 17 columns) of terse textual data.
In many of the columns, empty entries have been replaced with "." as a marker.
Working from the top of the columns downward, I want to replace each successive "." with the data value (non-".") from above until the next data value is found; at which time I want to replace the next sequence of "." with the new data value etc. E.g.

```
x     -->  x  
"."   -->  x  
y     -->  y  
"."   -->  y  
"."   -->  y  
z     -->  z  
"."   -->  z
```

I need to do this for all rows of data.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. -k-

Comment: Is there an assumption that there are no "." in a first row?

Comment: To Kuba -- In my case all first row entries contain no ".".

Comment: To All Respondees -your efforts are truly appreciated. Not only for their efficacy but for their pedagogical value as well. Thanks very much!

Comment: One further question re Simon Wood's blazingly fast solution: is the function 'f' doubly defined? I don't understand the usage. Can anyone point me to description? -k-

Comment: @Keith, yes, there are two definitions for the `f[]` in Simon's answer.

Comment: @Keith Each definition matches a different pattern of input; together they define a single function.  [This tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitionsOverview.html) may help.

Comment: [Related question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8682937/935879)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

How about

```
f[_, y_] := y
f[x_, "."] := x

fill[data_] := Transpose[FoldList[f, First[#], Rest[#]] & /@ Transpose[data]]
```

Comment: +1.  I think this one is going to be my favorite.

Comment: It is so fast :). +1

Comment: `Fold` is such a natural solution to this problem  -- I'm embarrassed I didn't think to try it.  It works row-by-row, too, if `f` is `Listable` and the data contain no lists: `fill[data_] := FoldList[f, First[data], Rest[data]]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, that's a neat alternative.

Comment: Just happened across this. Quite nice. My final attempt similar, you might get a chuckle from a prior (impractical, but kind of pretty in a way): `FixedPoint[
 ReplacePart[#, {r_, c_} /; (#[[r, c]] == ".") :> #[[r - 1, 
     c]]] &, data]`  ... +1, of course!

Answer (score 11):

`Map` approach:

```
g["."] := last;    g[x_] := x;
Map[(last = g[#]) &, Transpose[data], {2}]\[Transpose]
```

### Latest ideas, quite important remarks (in my opinion)

I have asked Keith about gaps in first row. ...and no one have paid atenttion (me too). It is crucial, this is what makes significant difference between this problem and problem linked by Mr. Wizard.

Why?, because this information allows us to effectively use `ParallelMap`.

First I thought, let `Transpose`->`Map`->`Transpose`, what a big deal. `Parallel Map` will also help each method, so result will be qualitatively the same but... it is not true.

**Conclusions:**

1. I am not able to help Simon's `ListFold` method with `ParralelMap` [(separate question)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26787/5478)
2. Methods's relative efficiency depends on "." density.
3. Methods's relative efficiency depends on data type.

It should depend of number_of_columns/avalible_threads but I haven't checked that. I have 2 cores.

Each method contains now `ParallelMap` (exept red one). 0x4A4D's works faster without parallelization so I left it too. Maybe implementation could have been better, codes are below plots.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Codes with methods upgraded with `ParallelMap`:**

```
(*Simon with and without parallelmap*)
f[_, y_] := y;f[x_, "."] := x;
fill[data_] :=  Transpose[FoldList[f, First[#], Rest[#]] & /@ Transpose[data]]

fillP[data_] := Transpose[ParallelMap[
        FoldList[f, First[#], Rest[#]] &,
        Transpose[data]]]
(*mine*)
g["."] := last;g[x_] := x;
ParallelMap[(last = g[#]) &, Transpose[data], {2}]\[Transpose];
(*0x4A4D's*)
fillblanks[list_, dummy_: "."] := Flatten[
  Map[
     ConstantArray[First[#], Length[#]] &,
     Split[list, MatchQ[#2, dummy] &]]]
(*Michael's*)
filldown2 = Transpose@ParallelMap[
 Module[{last = First[#]}, Function[{entry}, last = entry /. "." -> last] /@ #] &, 
 Transpose[#]] &;
```

**Testing procedure:**

```
time = {};
Do[(
k = 10^i;
data = Table[RandomChoice[{"1","."}], {k}, {4}]~Prepend~(Range@4);
AppendTo[time,
 {fill@data; // Timing // First,
  fillP@data; // Timing // First,
  ParallelMap[(last = g[#]) &, Transpose[data], {2}]\[Transpose]; //Timing // First,
  Transpose[fillblanks /@ Transpose[data]]; // Timing // First,
  filldown2@data; // Timing // First
}]
), {i, 3, 6, .5}]
```

In order to switch % of "." I have simply used `RandomChoice[{"1","."}]` (for 50%) and `RandomChoice[{"1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","."}]` for 10% :).

---

### First, single thread ideas

**Old** There was no `MapIndexed` way, so now it is:

```
f[d_, {x_, y_}] := If[d == ".", f[data[[x - 1, y]], {x - 1, y}], d]

MapIndexed[f, data, {2}]
```

**New** `Map` approach:

```
g["."] := last
g[x_] := x
Map[(last = g[#]) &, Transpose[data], {2}]\[Transpose]
```

And version which needs only `[[1,1]]` element to be different from `"."`:

```
Partition[
   (last = g[#]) & /@ Flatten[Transpose[data]]
, Length@data]\[Transpose]
```

33 sec for k=10^6, faster but not fast enough. I'll update plots later.

**methods comparison:**

tested on 7-column k-row matrix, where k = 10^1, 10^2...
Elements are strings.

```
data=Table[RandomChoice[{"1", "2", "3", "."}], {k}, {7}]~Prepend~(ToString /@Range@7);
```

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit heartened that my proposal is at least second best... :D

Comment: @0x4A4D I've thought mine would be :( but reference to data inside function have killed it :)

Comment: @0x4A4D I wasn't able to apply `ParallelMap` to Your solution, now Michael took Your place. Help me to improve the code :)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe there's a more efficient approach, but here's what I came up with:

```
data = {{"foo", "foo", "blah", "blah", "foo", "blah", "argh"},
        {"pfft", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "foo"},
        {"foo", ".", "foo", ".", "pfft", "blah", "."},
        {".", ".", "pfft", ".", ".", ".", "blah"},
        {".", "pfft", "blah", ".", ".", ".", "."},
        {"blah", ".", ".", ".", "argh", ".", "."},
        {"blah", "foo", "foo", "argh", ".", ".", "pfft"},
        {".", ".", "pfft", ".", "argh", ".", "."},
        {"foo", ".", "blah", ".", "argh", ".", "."},
        {"blah", "pfft", ".", "pfft", "foo", "argh", "."}};

fillblanks[list_, dummy_: "."] := 
    Flatten[ConstantArray[First[#], Length[#]] & /@ Split[list, StringMatchQ[#2, dummy] &]]

Transpose[fillblanks /@ Transpose[data]]
```

which yields

```
{{"foo", "foo", "blah", "blah", "foo", "blah", "argh"},
 {"pfft", "foo", "blah", "blah", "foo", "blah", "foo"},
 {"foo", "foo", "foo", "blah", "pfft", "blah", "foo"},
 {"foo", "foo", "pfft", "blah", "pfft", "blah", "blah"},
 {"foo", "pfft", "blah", "blah", "pfft", "blah", "blah"},
 {"blah", "pfft", "blah", "blah", "argh", "blah", "blah"},
 {"blah", "foo", "foo", "argh", "argh", "blah", "pfft"},
 {"blah", "foo", "pfft", "argh", "argh", "blah", "pfft"},
 {"foo", "foo", "blah", "argh", "argh", "blah", "pfft"},
 {"blah", "pfft", "blah", "pfft", "foo", "argh", "pfft"}}
```

Answer (score 5):

This question is arguably a duplicate of:  [Fill out blanks with a upcoming number in a list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2952/121)
There the filling is requested in reverse and for a single list, but the principle is the same.

Simon Woods already posted what is IMHO the most natural approach: `FoldList`, but as we are already restating earlier answers I'd like to share my own variations.

For each method I'll show application to a single list `v`; application to columns is easily accomplished with a double `Transpose`.

Heike's method using `FoldList` and `/.`:

```
v = {8, 3, ".", 1, ".", ".", 7, ".", 9, ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", 2, ".", 2, 6};

Rest @ FoldList[#2 /. "." -> # &, ".", v]
```

> ```
> {8, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2, 6}
> ```

Also of interest is Leonid's method with `Split`.  Here in a different style:

```
Join @@ (Table[#, {Length@{##}}] & @@@ Split[v, #2 === "." &])
```

> ```
> {8, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2, 6}
> ```

Simon's code is faster than either of these on unpacked (mixed) data:

```
SeedRandom[3]
v = Clip[RandomInteger[{-7, 9}, 350000], {1, ∞}, {".", 1}];

Rest@FoldList[#2 /. "." -> # &, ".", v]                        // Timing // First
Join @@ (Table[#, {Length@{##}}] & @@@ Split[v, #2 === "." &]) // Timing // First
f[_, y_] := y; f[x_, "."] := x; FoldList[f, First[v], Rest[v]] // Timing // First
```

> 0.2872
>
> 0.327
>
> 0.0936

However if the problem can be recast to packable data then a form that complies will be faster.  I'll use zero to represent fields that should be filled.

```
v = {8, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 7, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 6};

Rest @ FoldList[If[#2 == 0, ##] &, 0, v]
```

> ```
> {8, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 2, 2, 2, 6}
> ```

```
SeedRandom[3]
v = Clip[RandomInteger[{-7, 9}, 350000], {1, ∞}, {0, 1}];

ClearAll[f];

f[_, y_] := y; f[x_, 0] := x; FoldList[f, First[v], Rest[v]]  // Timing // First
Rest @ FoldList[If[#2 == 0, ##] &, 0, v]                      // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.0936
>
> 0.0212
> ```

I like the compact and self-contained nature of this code as well.

Comment: I love the use of `##` in the `If` statement!

Comment: @Simon Thanks. :-)

Comment: I have analyzed difference between those two questions, please take a look.

Answer (score 3):

Row by row:

```
Clear[datum];
SeedRandom[1];
datum[] := RandomInteger[{0, 9}];
tab = {RandomInteger[{0, 9}, 5]} ~Join~ RandomChoice[{8, 1} -> {".", x}, {9, 5}] /. x :> datum[]

filldown@tab
```

> ```
> {{ 1,   4,   0,   7,   0},
>  {".", ".", ".",  8,  "."},
>  {".", ".", ".", ".",  5},
>  {".", ".", ".", ".", "."},
>  {".",  7,   6,  ".", "."},
>  {".",  7,  ".", ".", "."},
>  {".", ".",  0,  ".",  1},
>  {".", ".", ".", ".", "."},
>  {".", ".",  0,  ".", "."},
>  {".", ".", ".", ".", "."}}
> ```

```
filldown = Module[{last = First[#]},
   Function[{row}, 
     last = ReplacePart[last, # -> Extract[row, #] & /@ Position[row, Except["."]]]] /@ #] &
```

> ```
> {{1, 4, 0, 7, 0},
>  {1, 4, 0, 8, 0},
>  {1, 4, 0, 8, 5},
>  {1, 4, 0, 8, 5},
>  {1, 7, 6, 8, 5},
>  {1, 7, 6, 8, 5},
>  {1, 7, 0, 8, 1},
>  {1, 7, 0, 8, 1},
>  {1, 7, 0, 8, 1},
>  {1, 7, 0, 8, 1}}
> ```

---

Down each column:

```
filldown2 = Transpose@Map[Module[{last = First[#]},
      Function[{entry}, last = entry /. "." -> last] /@ #] &, Transpose[#]] &

filldown2@tab
```

> Same as above.

Answer (score 2):

Caution: This answer is just for fun. `ReplaceRepeated` is *constantly* slow.

Using 0x4A4D's `data`:

```
#//.{pre___,a_,b:Longest["."..],post___}:>{pre,a,Sequence@@({b}/."."->a),post}&/@
  (data\[Transpose])\[Transpose]
```

Or,

```
Flatten[#//.{pre___,a_,b:Longest["."..],post___}:>{pre,a,{b}/."."->a,post}]&/@
  (data\[Transpose])\[Transpose]
```

Comment: I like everything based on patterns (+1) but it seems very slow for bigger tables :/

Comment: @Kuba `ReplaceRepeated` is always VERY slow.. This is just an answer for fun :)

Comment: I suspected it was just for fun but I was not aware how slow it would be. :) Nevertheless I still like it :)

Comment: @Kuba Be careful! `ReplaceRepeated` is a honey trap! :)

Comment: @Michael -- Thank you for your reference to other material.

Comment: Hi @Keith. I think you need to comment directly under your question to ensure Michael E2 being informed.

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing J.M's data

```
data =
  {{"foo", "foo", "blah", "blah", "foo", "blah", "argh"},
   {"pfft", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "foo"},
   {"foo", ".", "foo", ".", "pfft", "blah", "."},
   {".", ".", "pfft", ".", ".", ".", "blah"},
   {".", "pfft", "blah", ".", ".", ".", "."},
   {"blah", ".", ".", ".", "argh", ".", "."},
   {"blah", "foo", "foo", "argh", ".", ".", "pfft"},
   {".", ".", "pfft", ".", "argh", ".", "."},
   {"foo", ".", "blah", ".", "argh", ".", "."},
   {"blah", "pfft", ".", "pfft", "foo", "argh", "."}};
```

Using `SequenceReplace` (new in 11.3)

```
MatrixForm @ Transpose @ Map[
   Flatten @* SequenceReplace[{a_, b : "." ..} :> Array[a &, Length[{b}] + 1]],
   Transpose @ data]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `Split`, `SequenceCases` and `ReplacePart`:

```
f1[v_?VectorQ] := MapApply[Rule,
    Transpose[
            MapAt[Function[Position[Split @ v, Apply[Alternatives, #]]],
                Transpose[
                    SequenceCases[v,
                        {a_, b : Longest["." ..]} :> {{b}, 
         ConstantArray[a, Length[{b}]]}
                    ]
                ],
                {1}
            ]
        ]
   ];

f2[v_?VectorQ] := Flatten[ReplacePart[Split[#], f1@#]] &@v

Transpose@(f2 /@ Transpose@data) // MatrixForm
```

[image]