# Cross-Correlation with TimeSeries

Tags: time-series, signal-processing

How to find hidden relationship between two TimeSeries data sets? I normally compute the [Cross-Correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) function, but I cannot find an easy way of doing this on the [TimeSeries objects](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeries.html) in Mathematica.

Do you know an elegant way of computing Cross-Correlation between two TimeSeries objects?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The only *elegant* thing I've found that can be done for this question is the shifting of the time series with `TimeSeriesShift` to help get the answer.

```
{pepsi, mcds} = 
 TimeSeries[FinancialData[{"NYSE", #}, 
  "Price", {DateObject[{2012, 12, 31}], DateObject[{2015, 3, 31}], 
  "Week"}]] & /@ {"PEP", "MCD"}
```

Get to time series. `TimeSeriesShift` will shift the series the number of specified time units.

```
DateListPlot[{mcds, TimeSeriesShift[mcds, Quantity[-10, "Week"]]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"before", "after shifting"}]
```

[image]

This can be used to calculate the cross-correlation.

```
crossCorrelation[tsX_, tsY_, shift_?QuantityQ] :=
 Module[{μX = Mean@tsX, σX = 
    StandardDeviation@tsX, μY = Mean@tsY, σY = 
    StandardDeviation@tsY, tsYShift, xValues, yValues, minLength, 
   pairs},
  tsYShift = TimeSeriesShift[tsY, shift];
  xValues = 
   Select[tsX["Path"], #[[1]] <= tsYShift["LastTime"] &][[All, 2]];
  yValues = 
   Select[tsYShift["Path"], #[[1]] >= tsX["FirstTime"] &][[All, 2]];
  minLength = Min[Length /@ {xValues, yValues}];
  pairs = 
   Transpose[{xValues[[;; minLength]], yValues[[;; minLength]]}];
  Last[FoldList[
     Function[{running, next}, 
      running + (next[[1]] - μX) (next[[2]] - μY)], 0, 
     pairs]]/(minLength σX σY)
  ]
```

You will notice that many function can take `TimeSeries` objects without having to strip off the time column (e.g. `Mean`). This makes things a little easier.  Using `crossCorrelation` for the two time series the second series is shifted backwards and then the two series are truncated to hold the same number of points. I couldn't find a built-in function to truncate a time series.

```
crossCorrelation[pepsi, mcds, Quantity[-10, "Weeks"]]
(* -0.0492425 *)
```

This looks reasonable from the plot.

```
DateListPlot[{pepsi, TimeSeriesShift[mcds, Quantity[-10, "Week"]]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Pepsi", "McDonald's (-10 week shift)"}]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Using `"Values"` you can extract the numerical values of the time series and perform whatever statistical analysis you want on them.

For example, if the `TimeSeries`are financial data:

```
data1 = FinancialData["SBUX", 
   "Close", {{2013, 1, 1}, {2013, 12, 1}, "Day"}];
data2 = FinancialData["SBUX", 
   "Close", {{2013, 5, 1}, {2013, 6, 1}, "Day"}];
ts1 = TimeSeries[data1[[All, 2]], {data1[[1, 1]], Automatic, "Day"}];
ts2 = TimeSeries[data2[[All, 2]], {data2[[1, 1]], Automatic, "Day"}];
```

Then you can calculate the correlation as

```
corr = ListCorrelate[ts2["Values"], ts1["Values"]]
```

and `ListLinePlot[corr]` gives

[image]

If the times of the `TimeSeries` are not equally spaced, you can use `Interpolation` (on `ts["Times"]`) to upsample the data at equally-spaced coordinates and preform the analysis on that.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Edmund's answer I have written a function that will produce cross-correlation sweep. Excellent for sweeps, but not optimised for performance.

```
TSCorrelation[ts1_, ts2_] := Module[
  {aligned, r, z, seZ, ZtoR, up, down, error},
  aligned = Select[ 
     GatherBy[  Normal@ts1~ Join ~ Normal@ts2, First],
     Length[#] == 2 &] [[All, {1, 2}, 2]];
  (*chaeck if enough data is available*) 
  If[Length@aligned < 3, Return[
    <| "correlation" -> 0,  "error" -> 1.0 , 
     "error bounds" -> {1, 0}, "size" ->  Length@aligned |> ]];
  r = N@Correlation[   aligned[[All, 1]] , aligned[[All, 2]]  ];
  (* error estimate *)
  z = 0.5 Log[ (1 + r)/(1 - r)];
  seZ = 1/Sqrt[Length@aligned - 3];
  ZtoR[zz_] := (Exp[2 zz] - 1)/(Exp[2 zz] + 1);
  {up, down} = {ZtoR[z + seZ], ZtoR[z - seZ]};
  error = (up - down )/2;
  (* out *)
  <| "correlation" -> r,  "error" -> error , 
     "error bounds" -> {up, down}, "size" ->  Length@aligned |>
]
```

and

```
TSCrossCorrelation[ts1_, ts2_, unit_: "Day"] := Module[
  {minShift, maxShift, ccRaw},
  minShift = -QuantityMagnitude@
     DateDifference[ts1["FirstDate"], ts2["LastDate"], unit];
  maxShift = 
   QuantityMagnitude@
    DateDifference[ts2["FirstDate"], ts1["LastDate"], unit];
  ccRaw = Quiet@Table[
     Append[ TSCorrelation[TimeSeriesShift[ ts1, {shift, unit}], ts2],
       "shift" -> shift ],
     {shift, Range @@ Sort@{minShift, maxShift}}
     ];
  (*filter out high errors *)
  Select[ ccRaw, #["error"] <= 0.3 &]
]
```

Usage example:

```
data1 = FinancialData["SBUX", 
   "Close", {{2013, 1, 1}, {2013, 12, 1}, "Day"}];
data2 = FinancialData["SBUX", 
   "Close", {{2013, 5, 1}, {2013, 6, 1}, "Day"}];
ts1 = TimeSeries[data1[[All, 2]], {data1[[1, 1]], Automatic, "Day"}];
ts2 = TimeSeries[data2[[All, 2]], {data2[[1, 1]], Automatic, "Day"}];
cc = Dataset@TSCrossCorrelation[ ts1, ts2];
ListPlot @ cc[All, {"shift", "correlation"}]
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to **rasher's** answer to [Unragging a matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78903/unragging-a-matrix/78921) I have written:

```
PreFill := 
 Module[{t = ConstantArray["x", Length@Dates], 
    p = #[[All, 1]] /. 
      Dispatch@Thread@Rule[Dates, Range@Length@Dates]}, t[[p]] = #; 
   t] &


Filler[dt_] :=
 Module[{f, pr},
  f[x_, "x"] := x;
  f[_, x_] := x;
  pr = FoldList[f, FoldList[f, #][[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1]]][[-1 ;; 
       1 ;; -1]] & /@ dt;
  MapIndexed[(pr[[All, First@#2, 1]] = #1) &, Dates];
  pr]
```

to compute the correlation between timeseries of different lengths. For example, if you want to find the correlation between the stock prices of an us company and a german company you always have the problem that some dates are missing because of different bank holidays. In this case "fill" the missing value(s) with the preceding or following value.

**Example:**

```
pr = Map[FinancialData[#, "Price", {2012}] &, {"F:DAI", "F:VOW"}];

Dates = MapFirst@SelectFirst[pr, Length@# == Max@MapLength@pr &];

Correlation[First@#, Last@#] &[Map[Last, Filler@Map[PreFill, pr], {2}]]
```

> 0.92702